# i18n-friendly enum sorting in Oracle 11g

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I have many (30+) Java enums which are mapped to integer ids in the database. I would like to be able to sort by these without modifying many queries, and be able to index on the sort order.

Example - note that many of the other enums may have a dozen or so options, so aren't quite this trivial:

Table 1: Person
Name (varchar), Sex (enum)
Bob, 0
Fred, 0
Susan, 1
Jamie, 2

Java enum - 
Male(0),
Female(1),
Unknown(2)

I would like to be able to just do order by person.sex, and have the order be "Female", "Male", "Unknown". (or 1,0,2 in numeric order). Ideally this order would be variable based on language, but it would be ok to have 1 language/database.

I realize I could order by a case clause, but this would require changing a very large number of places in the application, including many dynamically generated queries.

I also support postgres, which allows me to define this as an enum (1, 0, 2), solving all of these problems, at least for 1 language/database. Something like this would be very valuable.

I have thought about just making a "sex" table with ids and names, and sorting by that. Unfortunately, to order the person table (many million entries) by sex, it takes quite a long time as I can then not make an index on the sex column (or at least one useful in sorting).

I have thought about using a custom type as well, but at that point am not quite sure how to integrate it with hibernate (custom types don't seem to actually be that flexible).

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.